# Execute sh with parameters in bash

Tags: bash, shell, daemon

I am coding a daemon to execute a service. The syntax is `./ctlscript.sh start`. When I execute `service openproject start` it should run this command, but it runs ./ctlscript.sh whitout a parameter and I get the usage. This is my script:

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: openproject
# Required-Start: $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop: $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: Openprject
# Description: This file starts and stops Openproject server
#
### END INIT INFO

OPENP_DIR=/opt/openprj

case "$1" in
 start)
   su administrador -c $OPENP_DIR/ctlscript.sh start
   ;;
 stop)
   su administrador -c $OPENP_DIR/ctlscript.sh stop
   ;;
 restart)
   su administrador -c $OPENP_DIR/ctlscript.sh stop
   sleep 20
   su administrador -c $OPENP_DIR/ctlscript.sh start
   ;;
 *)
   echo "Usage: openproject {start|stop|restart}" >&2
   exit 3
   ;;
esac
```

This is what I get when I run service openproject stop. It is the same when I launch `./ctlscript.sh` (without any parameter):

```
usage: /opt/openprj/ctlscript.sh help
       /opt/openprj/ctlscript.sh (start|stop|restart|status)
       /opt/openprj/ctlscript.sh (start|stop|restart|status) mysql
       /opt/openprj/ctlscript.sh (start|stop|restart|status) memcached
       /opt/openprj/ctlscript.sh (start|stop|restart|status) apache
       /opt/openprj/ctlscript.sh (start|stop|restart|status) subversion
       /opt/openprj/ctlscript.sh (start|stop|restart|status) openproject

help       - this screen
start      - start the service(s)
stop       - stop  the service(s)
restart    - restart or start the service(s)
status     - show the status of the service(s)
```

Comment: Just as a side note: if you want your script to run on bash only, change the shebang into `#!/usr/bin/env bash`. There is no guarantee that `/bin/sh` is actually bash, though it is likely on most systems since it's usually symlinked to it. Check `ls -la /bin/sh` when it doubt. Your script works just fine on my machine.

Comment: Ok thanks. I don't know why not in mine :(

Comment: You'll probably want to swap the script invocations for the `restart` action. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The argument to `-c` must be a single word, so

```
 su administrador -c "$OPENP_DIR/ctlscript.sh start"
```

For "restart", you should "stop" first, then "start"

Comment: Make sure you understand the difference between single quotes and double quotes here, it can make quite a difference. For example, the command `sudo sh -c "echo $USER"` gives a different result to `sudo sh -c 'echo $USER'`.